# How to "pass" an namespace as argument?

Tags: c++, namespaces

If I have the following code :

```
void foo1()
{
    NS1::Type1 instance1;
    NS1::Type2 instance2;
    NS1::Type3 instance3;
}

void foo2()
{
    NS2::Type1 instance1;
    NS2::Type2 instance2;
    NS2::Type3 instance3;
}
```

How to factorize this function ?

I can call foo1 from NS1, and foo2 from NS2.

Comment: Do you mean `using namespace NS1;` and `using namespace NS2;`? If not, what was your question again?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? Maybe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: In the project I working on, there are many duplicates codes, varying only by the namespaces used. So I try to find a way to factorize them. I could use templates, but the class names are same ; the only differences are about namespaces. Using templates could imply _many_ templates.

Answer (score 5):

> How to “pass” an namespace as argument?

There is no way to do that.

It is possible to write a reusable template for your foos if you use classes instead of namespaces:

```
struct NS1 {
    using Type1 = int;
    using Type2 = float;
    using Type3 = std::string;
};

struct NS2 {
    using Type1 = long;
    using Type2 = double;
    using Type3 = std::string;
};

template<class T>
void foo() {
    typename T::Type1 instance1;
    typename T::Type2 instance2;
    typename T::Type3 instance3;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using classes. I am going to see if I could use inline namespaces...